# Removing empty lines while reading a file in Dartlang

Tags: dart, dart-io

I have a file like:

```
A
B


C
D
```

Both `readAsLines()` and `readAsString() + string.split('\n')` give me:

```
[A, B, , , C, D]
```

What is the smartest way to get?

```
[A,B,C,D]
```

Answer (score 3):

One possibility would be:

```
import 'dart:io';

main() {
  File f = new File('test.txt');
  f.readAsLines().then((List<String> lines) {
    print(lines.where((String s) => s.isNotEmpty));
  });
}
```